# loaded the "FriendViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Tags: ios, facebook-fql

I was following this beautiful tutorial about how to Run FQL queries(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/) but unfortunately i am having an unexpected issue that I am not sure how to solve. I was able to follow pull data and follow along until the third step(after implementing it, the program crashes) I have went through my program just to see if i made errors or not but i did not see any. Can someone give me a suggestion about how I need to fix the outlet in this case? Thank you.

**FriendViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FriendViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *data;
@end
```

**FriendViewController.m**

```
#import "FriendViewController.h"

@interface FriendViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIToolbar *toolbar;
@end

@implementation FriendViewController

@synthesize data = _data;
@synthesize toolbar = _toolbar;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    // Add a toolbar to hold a Done button that will dismiss this view controller
    self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    self.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [self.toolbar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [self.toolbar sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                              target:nil
                              action:nil];

    self.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:space, doneButton, nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                           objectForKey:@"name"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:
                      [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                       [NSURL URLWithString:
                        [[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                         objectForKey:@"pic_square"]]]];
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}
/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.toolbar;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.toolbar.frame.size.height;
}
- (void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // Dismiss view controller based on supported methods
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) {
        // iOS 5+ support
        [[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
}
@end
```

Comment: You have to post the crash info that is displayed when it does. (like in xcode lower part it should say something like bad access error or something else)

Answer (score 0):

In `FriendViewController.xib`, the `view` connection from your Files Owner to your actual view was either disconnected or never connected in the first place.  Instead of being a pal and loading a view for you, UIViewController takes your app down with an exception (nifty).